# Entity Framework eager loading nested object graph, errors out to invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework, eager-loading, object-graph

Guess, I am missing to notify a navigation property to EF while eager loading nested graph. Please let me know what am I missing ?.

**My simplified Object graph**

```
Product (ProductId, IEnumerable<Task>, ProductStatusId, ProductStatus)

ProductStatus (ProductStatusId, Description)

Task (TaskId, ProductId, TaskStatusId, TaskStatus)

TaskStatus (TaskStatusId, Description)
```

**Trying to load Product => with its Tasks => with their TaskStatus**

```
.Include(p => p.ProductStatus)
.Include(p => p.Tasks)
.Include(p => p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskStatus))
```

Getting the following error :

> {"Invalid column name 'TaskStatus_ProductStatusId'.\r\nInvalid column
>   name 'ProductStatusId'}

Comment: Sounds like relationship setup issue. Please post your simplified classes with navigation properties/keys properties and data annotations/fluent setup included.

Comment: You are right Ivan Stoev, the fluent configuration was having wrong name. (We were writing hundreds of configurations, and this column name mapping is messed up).

Comment: Are you sure that your database is up to date and aligned with your object model?

Comment: Yes Bubi, they are fine. Your analysis is correct. In our project, it's neither code-first or DB first, we do models and DB separately and map them through fluent. That's where the issue got introduced, as we hard code column names there.

Answer (score 0):

This should Work

```
  _yourContext.Product   
  .Include(p => p.ProductStatus)
  .Include(p => p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskStatus))
```

You will not need

```
  .Include(p => p.Tasks)
```

Because ".Include(p => p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskStatus))" will get the Tasks and the TaskStatus from the Task Collection.